# Научить Cursor возвращать BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, cursor

Пишу приложение, оперирующее денежными расчётами. Очень часто приходится доставать значения из базы данных и переводить в  BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(cursor.getString(0)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Подскажите, как можно расширить класс Cursor, чтобы наряду с getInt(), getDouble()
реализовать getBigDecimal()?

Додумал до такого

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import java.math.BigDecimal;


public abstract class CursorMath implements Cursor {

    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(String value){

        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }
}
```

Но вышла ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Метод `rawQuery` является методом класса `SQLiteDatabase`, который помечен как `final` следовательно переопределить его нельзя. 
Можно написать обертку типа такой:

```
public class CustomCursor{

    private final Cursor cursor;

    public CustomCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(int index){

        return new BigDecimal(cursor.getString(index)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    // реализация остальных методов курсора, выглядеть может так

    public String getString(int index){
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}
```

И использовать так:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query();
CustomCursor cc = new CustomCursor(cursor);
BigDecimal bd = cc.getBigDecimal(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать шаблон проектирования [Декоратор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Т.е. ваш курсор будет таким:

```
public class CursorMath implements Cursor {

    private Cursor cursor;

    public CursorMath(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(Integer pos){
        return new BigDecimal(cursor.getString(pos));
    }
    // реализация всех других абстрактным методов
}
```

И создавать его надо соответственно:

```
CursorMath cursor = new CursorMath(db.rawQuery(query, null));
```